# ufw throws "bad port"

Tags: ufw

On Ubuntu Server, I try to open port 5432 for postgresql:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 5432/TCP
ERROR: Bad port
```

Postgresql is not currently running and netstat shows no processes currently using that port. What is going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ubuntu's [`ufw`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/ufw.8.html) command is case sensitive, the TCP should be lower case

```
sudo ufw allow 5432/tcp
```

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that one

Comment: Me too! I completely missed that! Even on 2018, I facepalmed really hard.